# Is there any special certificate required for system level apps to upload on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

My project is in iPhone, uses sysctl(mib, 2, &argmax, &size, NULL, 0) function.
   It is dealing with background processes in iPhone, accesses files modification time outside  my applications directory. 
apple guidelines says- "Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected".
will my app be accepted in appstore? or Is there any special certificate required for such apps to upload on iPhone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides that succinct answer above, you can always submit an appeal to the App Review Board (or maybe even send one in before your submission) and see if they will make an exception.

Here's where you can find information about that:

http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html

But yes, don't expect to get lucky with this kind of app. If you word your explanation or appeal very well, there's a chance you might get approved.

Comment: okay,is there any special certificate is required for such apps?

Comment: No. it'd be the same store certificate. Apple would have to review and approve (and good luck with that!).

Comment: Hi all,I have got response from apple saying that use of sysctl() is permitted.no offence.but you must not try to access data outside of your sandbox.there are many apps on appstore which lists active processes running in background.

Answer (score 1):

Apps that break the rules will be rejected.

Your app breaks the rules.

Yes it will be rejected.

Comment: ok,but how the apps like 'virusBarrier' which is an antivirus, is on appstore (as antiviruses work at system level only)?

Comment: virusBarrier doesn't work at the system level. It only check documents. This apple guide shows how to register to open documents such as attachments in emails: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW1

Comment: ok sosborn. can I distribute this app using enterprise distribution only for my clients? I'mean in that way I'll be bypassing appstore.

Comment: I have no idea, although I would be surprised if it was allowed. You should read through the enterprise development guides though to make sure.